# ¿Por qué se dice 'Veo una nube acercarse' en vez de 'Veo una nube acercándose?

Tags: verbos, sustantivos, conjugación, gerundio

He escuchado que se dice 'acercarse' en esa frase porque está en una sintagma nominal, pero me cuesta entender cuando hay que usar el infinitivo del verbo o el gerundio tras el sustantivo.

Comment: Ambas son correctas.

Answer (score 1):

Con verbos de percepción (*ver, oler, oír*), las dos formas, el infinitivo y el gerundio, son correctas como complemento objetivo, es decir, como una acción referida al objeto directo. En ambas oraciones:

- Veo una nube acercarse.

y

- Veo una nube acercándose.

lo que se acerca es el objeto directo "nube" (yo veo y la nube se acerca).

En este caso en particular, prácticamente no hay diferencia de significado. El gerundio podría sugerir un poco más de movimiento o gradualismo. En otros casos, el infinitivo trasmite la idea de completitud de la acción y el gerundio indica que la acción está en proceso, por ejemplo:

- Vi al niño cruzar la calle (I saw the boy cross the street): vi todo el proceso, desde que comenzó hasta que terminó de cruzar.
- Vi al niño cruzando la calle (I saw the boy crossing the street): vi parte del proceso, solo un momento en que el niño estaba cruzando la calle.

La diferencia es sutil, pero existe en mayor o menor grado según el verbo de que se trate. Como "acercarse" (a diferencia de "cruzar") no describe una acción que comienza y termina, sino más bien es un proceso en sí misma, la diferencia entre infinitivo y gerundio es despreciable o inexistente.

En [esta página de Internet](https://www.um.es/tonosdigital/znum22/secciones/estudios-19-complemento_predicativo.htm) que cita distintas gramáticas puede leerse que tanto el infinitivo como el gerundio pueden funcionar como complementos predicativos del objeto directo:

> También es posible encontrar construcciones en las que el núcleo
> verbal de la subordinada sustantiva de complemento predicativo es un
> infinitivo o un gerundio, los cuales en la mayor parte de los casos
> llevan un sujeto en CD (complemento directo) [...]:
>
> - Las veo saltar con la cuerda.
> - Dejé a mi sobrina bañándose.

Obviamente, se podría decir:

- Las veo saltando con la cuerda.
- Vi a mi sobrina bañándose/bañarse.

En ambos casos, el infinitivo y el gerundio tienen como sujeto al objeto directo "las" o "mi sobrina".

En el caso de "saltar", no hay diferencia entre el infinitivo y el gerundio pero, si dijera "saltar una vez", sólo se podría usar el infinitivo (acción con inicio y fin). En el caso de "bañarse", se podría aducir que el infinitivo se refiere a la acción completa mientras que el gerundio alude a un momento de la acción.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que haya una forma clara de diferenciación de uso entre una opción y otra. Por lo general, el infinitivo se utiliza por algo que está sucediendo en un tiempo indeterminado mientras que el gerundio es cuando sucede en este momento. Por ejemplo:

> Carlos está por llegar

Carlos está en camino, pero no hay un momento específico ni en tiempo ni en ejecución de la acción.

> Carlos está llegando

Es algo que está sucediendo en este preciso momento.

---

En el caso de la pregunta:

> Veo una nube acercarse

La nube esta a la vista pero su arribo no es algo que pueda ocurrir de manera inminente.

> Veo una nube acercándose

La nube está en movimiento actualmente y su llegada es (o puede ser) inmediata.

Answer (score 0):

La interpretación semántica o contenido proposicional de ambas oraciones es el mismo, pero aún así como en otras cosas, existen estructuras sintácticas rivales que pueden expresar el mismo contenido semántico:

(1a) Fue triste que los enemigos *destruyeraan* la ciudad

(1b) La destrucción de la ciudad por los enemigos fue un hecho triste

Esencialmente (1a) y (1b) significan lo mismo, pero en la primera se recurre a una oración subordinada conjugada y en la segunda se recurre a un sintagma nominal complicado. En las oraciones del ejemplo sucede lo mismo:

(2a) [Veo una nube [PRO acercarse]] / (2b) [Veo una nube [acercándose]]

En (2a) tenemos una oración subordinada de infinitivo, mientras que en la segunda "acercándose" es un adjunto al sintagma verbal (un complemento circunstancial de modo, en una terminología más tradicional).

La demostración de (2a) es una oración subordinada se obtiene comparando estas dos:

(3a) quiero [PRO irme] / (3b) quiero [que te vayas]

Puede verse por comparación, que podemos analizar que los dos verbos están en oraciones diferentes.